# Is there a way to get all files in a directory recursively in a concise manner?

Tags: raku

I mean usable in one-liners. For example this:

```
raku -e 'dir(".")==>say()'
```

prints all files and directories in the current directory. How do I update it so it works recursively (without libraries and/or user-defined routines)? Or is it not possible?

I saw the `:recursive` flag mentioned somewhere, but that doesn't work:

```
> raku -e 'dir(".", :recursive)==>say()'
Cannot resolve caller dir(Str:D, :recursive); none of these signatures matches:
    (IO(Any) $path, Mu :$test!)
    (IO(Any) $path)
    (Mu :$test!)
    ()
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

It could be useful in environments with missing shell tools (on Windows) or with different versions/forks of common tools.

Answer (score 14):

Documentation for [`&?BLOCK`](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#&?BLOCK) actually gives its example for your use case, so here is a way:

```raku
for '.' {
    .Str.say when !.IO.d;
    .IO.dir()».&?BLOCK when .IO.d # let's recurse a little! 
}
```

- it starts from the current directory `'.'`
- if it's *not* a directory (`!.IO.d`), then stringify and print
- else, it's a directory; so get the `.dir` of that and repeat this procedure recursively (thanks to `&?BLOCK`) over all contents (thanks to `>>`) of this directory

  - &?BLOCK refers to what is between the curly brackets (with [the topic variable](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#The_$__variable) `$_`)
  - `>>` (or `»`) is the [hyper method call operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#methodop_%C2%BB._/_methodop_%3E%3E.) that is essentially giving a `map` behaviour here (but it has more to in it; you can see the documentation and/or [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/comments/zg4rrq/behavior_difference_with_map_vs_hypered_nonce))

This can be rearranged and modified a little to get

```raku
!.IO.d ?? .put !! .IO.dir».&?BLOCK for "."
```

- the 2 `when` checks are unified into a ternary since they are collectively exhaustive and mutually exclusive
- `.Str.say` is actually `.Str.gist.put` but `put` would be already stringifying and the gist of a string is itself, so `.Str.say` is reducible to `.put`
- no need for parantheses after `dir` to disambiguate it from anything, so we erase that as well
- we switch to the statement modifier version of the for loop since we have a single statement going on
- here no curlies are present but there is still a block attached to the for loop (comprising of that single statement), so `&?BLOCK` still works

Comment: Thanks for providing an explanation! On another note, does SO already support syntax highlighting for Raku? It seems to be the case now.

Comment: hi @uzluisf, thanks for the response and the edits. i've used "lang-raku" in a hope to color the code for a couple of times now and it seemed to work, yet with your query i looked at the HTML of this page and see "hljs language-ruby"... so unfortunately no support yet it seems. (not listed in [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) but [this](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlightjs-raku) exists; not sure how easy it is to take some action there for the support.)

Comment: You're welcome, @Mustafa Aydın! That makes sense, I've seen `lang-perl` being used to get around that since both Raku and Perl share quite a bit of syntax. It's interesting that `lang-raku` gets turned into syntax highlighting for Ruby

Comment: Maybe cherry pick from `{.d ?? .dir».&?BLOCK !! $_}('.'.IO)`? I DRY'd the `.IO`. Eliminated double negative (`!` and `!!`). Yielded `$_` instead of running `.put`. (`»` semantics mean `.put` may (actually technically *should*) list files in random order. That may not be OK. Yielded values are kept ordered). I topicalized with `(...)` rather than `for` which was a poor choice in the doc example imo. Also, for your code to work with `==>say()`, it needs to be an expression, not a statement. You may as well invoke the block rather than use a `for` which would then need to be wrapped in parens.

Comment: so as a 1-liner ```raku -e '{.d ?? .dir».&?BLOCK !! .put}(".".IO)'``` ? maybe

Comment: @librasteve Maybe, but that would still have the problem that *`»` is specified to iterate in randomized order*. (Even if some version of Rakudo happens to iterate sequentially instead.) One way to solve that is to return values like I did (because hypers return values in the same order as the input). Another way is to not use `»` but instead a "regular" mapping function which is all that is functionally wanted anyway. For example, `raku -e '{.d ?? .dir.map(&?BLOCK).eager !! .put}(".".IO)'` would work. (`map` is lazy so one has to explicitly force eager evaluation.) Not concise imo, but works.

Answer (score 11):

There is no quick solution in Raku core.

There are several solutions in the Raku ecosystem.  Personally, I prefer [`paths`](https://raku.land/zef:lizmat/paths).  But then I'm the author of that module, and thus biased :-)

EDIT:

```
$ zef install paths
$ raku -Mpaths -e '.say for paths'
```

Comment: so that's ```raku -e 'use paths; .say for paths(:recurse)'```

Comment: is paths module in the standard rakudo distribution?

Comment: @librasteve or maybe: `raku -Mpaths -e  '.say for paths(:recurse);'`

Comment: Well, it works. But is not without external dependencies. I can't just say "use this one-liner in Raku", I have to also write a script or description how to install the library (and how to install zef, because you can have rakudo without it...).  

Why isn't this functionality part of Raku standard library? I thought focus of Raku was (at least in part) on scripting. Its often very terse syntax is ideal for powerful one-liners.

Answer (score 9):

Adapting the answer from the [Raku Docs](https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir):

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @stack = ".".IO;
            my $all-files = gather while @stack {
              with @stack.pop {
                when :d { @stack.append: .dir };
                .take
              };
            };
            $all-files.join("\n").put;'
```

Of course, with Raku you don't have to worry about mashing that answer onto one physical line:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @stack = ".".IO; my $all-files = gather while @stack { with @stack.pop { when :d { @stack.append: .dir }; .take }; }; $all-files.join("\n").put;'
```

Note, in the one-liner each closing-`}` curlie is followed by a semicolon. Raku makes them optional if followed immediately by a newline (at least that's how I understand it). See link below.

https://docs.raku.org/language/syntax#Separating_Statements_with_Semicolons